# EIGRP manual summarization prevent dual query

Tags: cisco, cisco-commands, eigrp, route-summarization

In EIGRP, manual summarization will prevent/ limit dual query. Is it true ?
How can we limit the ***dual query*** by introducing manual summary ?

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this might help:

https://networkdirection.net/EIGRP+Design

Also check out the references on the page.

Basically, summarization provides a natural boundary where queries are stopped.

Comment: Link-only answers are highly discouraged because links can go bad over time, and this site is meant to be a research archive. You should quote the relevant text in your answer, and provide the link for proper attribution.